# How do I set $0.00 products as "Included" on the Wordpress cart page?

Tags: wordpress, function, price

Wordpress 6.2, Woocommerce 7.4, custom theme based on underscore.

I have tried the below code with no luck:

```
function cl_price_override( $price, $product ) {
   if ( $product->get_regular_price()  == 0 ) {
       $price = "Included";
   }

   return $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cl_price_override', 100, 2 );
```

Comment: Did you copy the `cart.php` from the Woocommerce plugin folder (under `woocommerce/templates/cart/`) to your theme folder? Once you do that, you should be able to play around with the positioning.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I test if the price is $0.00 from there? What function calls the price when added to the cart?

Comment: I really want to do it from functions.php so I don't have to keep themes updated.